# Django-rest-api many to many send in json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use Django-rest-framework and I try to create method in django model,that returns info about other object to serializers.py
serializers.py

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    performer = PerformerSerializer(
    source='get_performers',
    read_only=True,many=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Master
        fields = ('first_name', 'performer')

class Stream(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey('Master', null=True, default=None)

class Catalog(models.Model):
    performer = models.ForeignKey('Performer', blank=True)
    stream = models.ForeignKey('Stream', null=True, default=None)
class Performer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
class Master(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_performers(self):
        streams = Stream.objects.filter(master=self)
        catalogs = Catalog.objects.filter(stream__in=streams).order_by('-datetime')[:10]
        catalogs = reversed(catalogs)
        performers = Performer.objects.filter(catalog__in=catalogs)
        return performers
```

I get error.By rest-apy I get equals object,but it is wrong.

```
{
    "first_name": "Master",
    "performer": [
        {
            "id": 1,
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
        }
}
```

Comment: why cant you send just catalog and call performer at front end like {{singlecatalog.performer.name}} or you can send value list using catalogs.objects.values('performer.name')

Comment: @Vicmathur Because I use rest-api and don't mix front and back end

Comment: If you are using django rest framework, then it can be done using serializers.. If you are using DRF, then I can give you an example..

Comment: @zaidfazil I use Django-rest-framework,but in this example I get error, because  performers = catalogs.performers

Comment: Does your `Catalog` model has any relationship with `Stream`? Your code doesn't show any.. How can we assume such, when you are performing your query, `Catalog.objects.filter(stream__in=....)` ?? doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @zaidfazil sorry,I  fix It . In Catalog.objects.filter(stream__in=....) I get all catalogs with stream equals one of streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `property` decorator on your model method and use it in the `ModelSerializer`,

```
def get_performers(self):
    streams = Stream.objects.filter(master=self)
    catalogs = Catalog.objects.filter(stream__in=streams).order_by('-datetime')[:10]
    catalogs = reversed(catalogs)
    performers = Performer.objects.filter(catalog__in=catalogs).distinct()
    return performers
```

Comment: It is not JSON serializable

Comment: Did you use it in a `ModelSerializer`??

Comment: Yes,I use it with 2 variants. Send list and query. In variant with query I see performers,but not different. Performers are equal,but it is error

Comment: I fix question and add response

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? Is it because duplicate items are returning? Or does the results are incomplete?

Comment: I mean that It duplicates items,but now I add new Item and It only 1 in list of performer.It duplicates only with id=1

Comment: Edited my answer.